# Name of this Formula [Spherical Earth projected to a plane]

Tags: calculus, geometry, terminology

I am using a formula to calculate the distance between two coordinates. Basically this is the Pythagorean theorem. I saw this formula on Wikipedia and it works perfectly for my use case. However I would like to have some more background on this formula, but I have no Idea how I could find it. It is not linked on Wikipedia.

Does anybody has an Idea, what's the name of this function?

[image: The Formula]

[Link to Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance#Spherical_Earth_projected_to_a_plane)

Comment: Well as you said, this is the pythagorean theorem. I doubt *every* application of the theorem has a different name. It is quite widely used, you know.

Comment: Thanks, ok. I basically created my own derivation for that formula, so I feel quite safe using it. Everybody interessted in doing the same? Basically it is quite obvious if you read about the equirectangular projection.